# How to share docker containers between machines

Tags: wordpress, docker, containers, share

I have a container that has a wordpress website and one with MySQL, I need to share this docker with a friend of mine so that he and I have the same development environment. How would it be possible to do this?

I imagine it's something similar to docker load and docker import

Answer (score 0):

[Here is](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-exportimport-containers-with-docker/) an alternative to the better Docker Hub solution:

**Image Export**

```
docker export EXPORT_NAME | gzip > EXPORT_NAME.gz
```

**Image Import**

```
zcat EXPORT_NAME.gz | docker import - EXPORT_NAME
```

After that you have, by the `docker run` command, to crate the container.

I suggest you to use [external volumes mapping](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) in order to GZIP and export containers data too.

Comment: With this I would have the image in my docker, what is the next step to create a container with it?

Comment: By the image you must use the `docker run` command with the arguments you need. I try to integrate my post.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're both developers, I'd share the code rather than images. If you both have the code, Dockerfiles and docker-compose files, you can build the containers on your machines.

Use Github or something similar to share the code.

Sharing the images would be a good solution if one of you were a developer and the other weren't.